# how to calculate this limit? calculus I.

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 -3x} -2}{2^x-2^4}$$

I cannot use l'hospitale rule or any other,just with modificating the limit,it's for calculus I.

Comment: I would rationalize the numerator. Then use the that $(2^x)'|_{x=4}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{2^x-2^4}{x-4}$

Comment: we can't use derivatives so that 2nd part is really not helping thankyou anyways, i was thinking to change that part inot something like : (2^x -1)/(x) because it makes it ln2 but i don't how

Comment: Oh so we can't use the definition of derivative either? Like you know $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0)$

Comment: we haven't define it yet, we had only defined functions, no derivatives yet, and i think it's not going to be getting any points on the exam so this wouldn't help,  i can only check myself with it after i solve it but it's not really useful for the exam itself

Comment: So are we suppose to guess the limit numerically?

Comment: yeah we can only use it with modificating and use of those known limits like some of the most basic known limits

Comment: I'm not sure what basic limits you know

Comment: Are you saying you know or are given that $\lim_{ x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2^x-1}{x}=\ln(2)$ ?

Comment: hm maybe i should use a new variable? that could help maybe

Comment: yea that is something i know

Comment: ok I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 -3x} -2}{2^x-2^4} =\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{\sqrt{x^2 -3x} -2}{2^x-2^4} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2 -3x} +2}{\sqrt{x^2 -3x} +2}=\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{x^2 -3x -4}{(2^x-2^4)(\sqrt{x^2 -3x} +2)}=\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{(x-4)(x+1)}{(2^x-2^4)(\sqrt{x^2 -3x} +2)}=\lim_{x\to 4} \frac{x-4}{2^x-2^4} \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2 -3x} +2}=\frac{1}{(2^x)'|_{x=4}} \cdot \lim_{x \rightarrow 4}\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2 -3x} +2} \\ \text{ You said you are given that } \\ \lim_{u \rightarrow 0} \frac{2^u-1}{u}=\ln(2) \text{ Sub in } u=x-4 \\ \lim_{x \rightarrow 4}\frac{2^{x-4}-1}{x-4}=\ln(2)  \text{ multiply both sides by } 2^4 \\ \lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{2^x-2^4}{x-4}=2^4 \ln(2)\\ $

Comment: So you can replace $(2^x)'|_{x=4}$ with what I just wrote.

Comment: @someguy95 Strange because above you said derivatives could not be used in the solution.

Comment: @zhw. But he did say we could know this $\lim_{ x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2^x-1}{x}=\ln(2)$ So I manipulated this for what I needed. The $(2^x)'|_{x=4}$ was something I wrote before I knew we couldn't use derivatives instead of editing the whole thing, I just used that as a placeholder for the algebraic work on $\lim_{ x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2^x-1}{x}=\ln(2)$ to show from that we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow 4} \frac{2^x-2^4}{x-4}=2^4 \ln(2)$.

Comment: OK, but still strange. How could someone know that limit and not know derivatives?

Comment: I agreed. It would be kind of useful to know why that limit is before using it. I guess they kinda of showed it maybe with a numerical approach which I really hate those approaches because really doesn't always give you exact limit number. But I don't know and maybe I shouldn't make any guesses here. :p

Comment: We have this as a "known limit",we will probably prove it with detivatives next semester.